# How to check if a socket is in use in c, to perform multiple simultaneous writes on single socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to write and read through a socket using TCP connection. Many workers write to the same socket. But they can't write at the same time. So one of them can write each time and the rest of them wait. How can I know if something is being written in the socket at the moment? Is there any system call. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if there is such a call, but why not use mutexes instead? Lock the mutex when the socket is being written to, and unlock when done.

Comment: That's what i have done, but I would like to use another way (for no serious reason). Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want high performance, what you should do instead is to have a single thread which manages the socket, and use in-memory queues to publish data from the workers to the socket manager.  This can be done lock-free without too much trouble, and it may improve throughput if your workers can chew on other tasks instead of waiting for their turn to use the socket.

A potentially interesting alternative is to use UDP instead of TCP.  Then the senders probably do not need to synchronize at all, since it's message-oriented (i.e. messages won't be partially sent if they are short enough).  You can even use multiple sockets to write to the same UDP address.  But attempting this would require a lot of care and consideration of what's reading on the other end.

Comment: I have to use TCP not UDP.

Comment: Why would that be the approach to use for high performance? It seems like using a single thread would force lots of unneeded context switches just because data was written from the "wrong" thread.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'm sorry but I don't follow what you're saying.  Particularly about context switches--what do you mean exactly?  There would be no "wrong" and "right" threads--all worker threads would send the data they want to write to a single writer thread which does nothing but read queued messages from workers and send them.  This can provide high performance because there are no locks required and a single core can deal with all networking while others ignore it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck There would be wrong and right threads. Only the one "special" thread would be the right thread. If any other thread wanted to write data to the socket, an utterly pointless context switch would be needed to get the "right" thread running. A much better design is this -- if a thread wants to write to the socket, and the application-level queue is empty, it just writes. If all the data is taken, as it usually will be, no context switch is needed and no other thread needs to run. You're optimizing the wrong thing -- locks are cheap, context switches are expensive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: thanks for the explanation, I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can send everything in a single `send()` or `sendmsg()` what you're asking for isn't even necessary. These calls (a) are atomic and (b) don't return until all the data has been transferred from the application to the kernel, in blocking mode.

Comment: Yes but you never know when a short write will happen (the buffer may be nearly full).  When a short write occurs then you'll be in trouble if you haven't designed for it.

Answer (score -1):

TCP/UDP sockets can be used simultaneously (in parallel threads) for read and write operations. That means read operation in one thread and write operation in other thread. But Doing same operation (read or write) on one thread simultaneously is not applicable. That means multiple threads doing write (or read) operation on a single socket is not thread safe without any lock on socket.

So if you want multiple workers to write on a single socket simultaneously means you need to create threads for each workers and you need to lock the socket before going for write operation. This requires n threads for n workers.

Comment: Your fourth sentence does not follow in any way from your third sentence. It is a complete *non sequitur.*